# CiviCRM cron job failing under Joomla 3.7

Tags: joomla

I updated to Joomla 3.7 and shortly thereafter, my CiviCRM cron job started failing. When I hit the URL in a browser, I get:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on null in
>   /home/public_html/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php on line
>   71

That's PHP 5.6.30 and it's a little different on PHP 7.0.16 (with max reporting on):

> Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Call
>   to a member function get() on null

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.18. This looks like a CiviCRM issue since my other cron job works fine.

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18390/cron-error-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-in-libraries-joomla-sessio looks related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a civi issue - it is a joomla issue that impacts other modules as well 
the fix is in j 3.71 
It is a 6 line patch and 1 line deletion

I have tested it and it works if you want to patch it yourself

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/15605

Comment: Thanks! Words of wisdom: Always wait until the first maintenance release of a major update before you upgrade your site.