# CRON Error: Trying to get property of non-object in /.../libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php on line 74

Tags: joomla, php, cron, session, cookies

How do I resolve this error, 'Trying to get property of non-object in /.../libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php on line 74'? Here's line 74 or the joomla.php file, $cookie = $this->input->cookie;. This started after updating the site to Joomla 3.7 and PHP 7.0, but also shows up with PHP 5.6. The site is running CiviCRM 4.7.18.

Comment: [This related question seems to have a Joomla patch available for you.](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18377/149) - seems like it's fixed in Joomla 3.7.1?