# Cron is not working after upgrading to latest version CiviCRM (4.7.29) and Joomla (3.8.4)

Tags: joomla, cron-job, cron

Recently upgraded to CiviCRM to latest (4.7.29) and Joomla (3.8.4.) installation to the latest version. After the upgrade cron is stopped working.

Getting below error while running cron using URL
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with running Joomla 3.8 and Civi](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20492/issues-with-running-joomla-3-8-and-civi)

Comment: What were you coming from - there is an old thread about joomla and cron issues https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18369/civicrm-cron-job-failing-under-joomla-3-7

Comment: See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21203. There isn't a complete solution yet.